# Android notification types with BuzzBox sdk

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a weather alarm application on Android.
I've integrated the buzzbox scheduler and I've written a task to check the weather condition every 3 hours using the cron string  "0 */3 * * 1,2,3,4,5,6,7" as described here http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/quickstart

I have 2 notification types: "bad-weather" and "weather-alert" and I'm creating the messages like this:

```
if (ALERT == type) {
    notification = new NotificationMessage("weather-alert","Weather Alert!","Tomorrow: Severe Weather",weatherDetails,R.id.icon_weather_alert);
} else {
    notification = new NotificationMessage("bad-weather","Bad Weather","Tomorrow: Bad Weather",weatherDetails,R.id.icon_weather_bad);
}
```

How can I set up vibration for the first notification and a sound for the second type?
Also, I only see one configuration section in the settings activity. Can I open up a different configuration settings for each type of notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use different configuration setting in code just add:

```
    new NotificationMessage("weather-alert","Weather Alert!","Tomorrow: Severe Weather",weatherDetails,R.id.icon_weather_alert)
          .setNotificationSettings(true, false, false)
```

where the parameters are

```
setNotificationSettings( doSound , doVibrate , doLed)
```

the Notification Settings include can include different section for each of your notification type if you declare them in the manifest.xml

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="SchedulerPreferenceActivity.notificationTypes" 
    android:value="bad-weather,weather-alert" />
<meta-data 
    android:name="SchedulerPreferenceActivity.notificationTypesLabels" 
    android:value="Bad Weather,Weather Alert" />
<meta-data 
    android:name="SchedulerPreferenceActivity.notificationTypes.defaultSettings.bad-weather" 
    android:value="statusBar=enabled,vibrate=disabled,led=disabled,sound=disabled" />
<meta-data 
    android:name="SchedulerPreferenceActivity.notificationTypes.defaultSettings.weather-alert" 
    android:value="statusBar=enabled,vibrate=disabled,led=disabled,sound=enabled" />
```